Why does `blake2b` on a `numpy` array give different results in different machines?
I ran the following code in two different machines:
import numpy as np
from hashlib import blake2b

print(blake2b(np.array([1, 2, 3])).hexdigest())

The two machines print a different result. Why could this happen? I am using the same Python and numpy version in both. One is Linux, and the other one is Windows, both 64-bit little endian. If I print the bytes from the array, they are identical.

Is this NumPy 2.x or 1.x? If it's 1.x, the default integer dtype is 32-bit on Windows.

"If I print the bytes from the array, they are identical." - how did you do that?

@user2357112 np.array([1, 2, 3]).tobytes() in numpy version 1.26.4

Actually, you are right, the difference is in the number of bits. They looked equal but they are not, as in Linux I have more 0s

It is always a good idea to specify the dtype of array IMHO. The default dtype may change in a future version, it can change from one OS to another, or even between two variation of the same OS. And the type can be dependent of the input data (which is often bad thing). Not to mention is is often a good idea to use small type to speed things up or to reduce the memory footprint. Here it is pretty critical for hashing (you cannot expect the same output between np.float64, np.int64 and np.int32 for example).
